# User Session lost after number of cookies exceeds in IE11/Edge - Browser Cookie limit

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

We are experiencing an issue and appreciate any help on it please.

In our application, AJAX(using simple $.ajax with a POST ) requests are getting html content from server and it all works fine in Chrome/FF/Safari but user session is lost in IE and Edge if the size of the returned content exceeds 30kb. If the returned payload size < 30 KB it all works fine in IE as well. So basically the ajax request returns successfully but we can see that session cookie is lost in subsequent request.

**Please note that same ajax handling mechanism is working fine on a number of other servers.**

Attached are the details of request/response headers of working and non working 
environments

Request response headers  - snapshot from working environment 
[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP9IO.jpg)

Request response headers  - snapshot from Non working environment 
[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qibon.jpg)

Please note the difference in response headers. Kindly let us know if you need any more information on this.

Comment: try to enable "protected mode" for the security zone that the site is in

Comment: another website with similar ajax handling is working in the IE . i have anyway tried enabling 'protected mode' but it does't help.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turned out to be be browser cookie limit. IE11+ Impose a limit of 50(increased from 20) cookies per domain and we were exceeding this limit. IE simply knocks out the older cookies if this limit is exceeded(Including the session cookie).

http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/941495/internet-explorer-increases-the-per-domain-cookie-limit-from-20-to-50